# Consuming API Curl to Java Application

Tags: java, curl, https, digest-authentication

I have an URL that requires me digest auth using username and password.

> curl -k --digest -u user:password https://api.uni5.net/cliente

But have no idea how to use Digest in get Request for Java application.
I'm searching for a simple way, cuz actually we dont use Java in our development, but now we need to use it inside the server.

Thanks for help!